# Make Python script run automatically + SQL database

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, automation

I have done many research on the forum but I didn't find a clear answer to my question.

I have created a python code which extracts data from a website and put it in a SQL database (with SQLITE). 
Now, I would like to make it run 24 hours a day on a server so that it collects data at each moment. 
Although I know how to code, I don't have a broad knowledge of IT in general.

Would you know by chance how to solve my problem ?

Edit: I was more thinking about putting my scripts on a cloud server to make it run instead of running it directly from my pc.

Thank you very much.

Lcs

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options:

1) You use a simple "while true" and "wait" in python, so the script is running constantly.

```
import time
while True:
    # Code
    time.sleep(5) # goes to sleep for 5 seconds
```

You can also do this in shell script (infinite loop+sleep) and then run the program when you want.

2) You can use cronjobs to run the pytho script. You basically have the script the will scrap the website and it will be launched every X seconds/minutes/hours. You can read more about how to use cronjobs in Google

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Such option would force me to let my computer turned on everytime. Is there any option where I can put my python script on a server which runs my script for me ? On the cloud or something

Comment: 1. Upload the file to the server. 2. Connect to the server using the terminal. 3. Open tmux, and execute the script in there. 4. Close tmux and close the connection. Note that the server has to obviously be working 24/7 then.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what system you are using (Unix or windows) you can use either:
1. [Windows Task Scheduler](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721931(v=ws.11).aspx) for Windows
2. [Crontab](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm) for Unix